# How to escape from slash "/" in windows 8?

Tags: windows, escaping, slash

I want to create an Microsoft Outlook folder's shortcut on my desktop at my work. However, we use a specific plug-in in our outlook that creates folders with "/" in the name, e.g. "Mamamia 2016/2017". When I try to create a shortcut with target:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /select "outlook:\\Mamamia 2016/2017"
```

this outlook folder cannot be opened.

I use Windows 8.

Comment: Are you sure `/select` expects `"outlook:\\Mamamia 2016/2017"` (vs. `"outlook:Mamamia 2016/2017"`)?

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, it works for folders that haven't got "/" in the name

Comment: That's not what I was asking. I was asking for the correct syntax, and the `/select` command line switch [apparently](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Outlook-for-Windows-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6) expects `"outlook:Mamamia 2016/2017"`.

Comment: I think the syntax used by me is correct because when I try to use the proposition from the link, the folder cannot be found / opened (applicable for the folders with name without "/"). I have read this site: (https://www.msoutlook.info/question/create-desktop-shortcut-to-an-outlook-folder)

Comment: Nowhere on [that page](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/create-desktop-shortcut-to-an-outlook-folder) does it prescribe to use an `outlook:\\ ` prefix.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. But does it make any difference on windows? The path of the folder <Mamamia 2016/2017> begins with "\\" like other folders in my mailbox and '/select' works with them. My point is how to cope with "/" in the '2016/2017'. I think there is a problem. –

Comment: Does it make a difference whether you type `http://example.com/` or `http:\\example.com/` into your browser? If you insist that you must violate a contract only to look for a solution to that violation, I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your help and your time. I have mentioned that unfortunately the proposition from your link does not work '<outlook:Mamamia 2016/2017>'

Comment: BTW I cannot change the folder name because I have no right to change it (as I have mentioned my mailbox is at my work, folders are created by other department). The violation is not my fault.